# Entity Framework 6 is appending underscore with foreign key columns

Tags: entity-framework, sql-server-2008, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I am using entity framework version 6 in my MVC5 application. I data model (.edmx) contains 2 entities **User** and **Role** corresponding to my tables in the database **Users** and **Roles**.

**Users** table contains columns: Id int, Name nVarchar(100), **RoleId** int (RoleId has foreign key constraint with Roles.Id)

**Roles** table contains columns: Id int, Name nVarchar(100)

My Entity model is generating the correct entities as per table structure.

Now when I am querying **User** entity (_db.Users.ToList()) from DB context, entity framework is looking for Role_Id column in user table instead of RoleId column, hence resulting in error.

So my question is why entity framework query generator is looking for Role_Id column while querying entity?

Answer (score 0):

Users and Roles would normally have a many-to-many relationship so you should have the corresponding relationships defined in both Users and roles.

```
public class Users
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles{ get; set; }
}

public class Role
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<User> Users{ get; set; }
}
```

You can also explicitly define the association as an entity if you'd like to add more attributes to the relationship:

```
public class UserRoles// Association table implemented as entity
{
    public int UserId{ get; set; }
    public virtual User User{ get; set; }
    public int RoleId{ get; set; }
    public virtual Role Role{ get; set; }
    public DateTime AssignmentDate{ get; set; }
}
```

You can also define the relationship explicitly http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Finally, you can also use DataAnnotions [Create Foreign Key using Data Annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000907/create-foreign-key-using-data-annotations)

Comment: Thanks, but my question is why entity framework query generator is looking for Role_Id column while querying entity?

Comment: This is happening because EF doesn't understand that RoleId is a foreign key so it is adding a new foreign key field for you. The EF convention for naming automatically inserted foreign key fields is tablename_Id, which is exactly what you are seeing. If you post your class definition code, we'll be able to tell you what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen when I defined my fields/properties incorrectly in EF.

Incorrect/original (adds an `_`)

```
    public Guid PCardRequestLineItemId;
    public PCardRequestLineItem PCardRequestLineItem;
```

Correct (no `_` added)

```
    public Guid PCardRequestLineItemId { get; set; }
    public virtual PCardRequestLineItem PCardRequestLineItem { get; set; }
```