# VB.NET can't seem to link data between two EF code first tables

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, ef-code-first

I'm trying to create a Bookings/Accounts database using EF code first and am having trouble with linking data

**A Bit of Background**

The Database has, at the moment 6 tables brought together in this context, but at the moment I'm just trying to get associations sorted for the following

```
Public Class CompanyContext
    Inherits DbContext
    Public Property Drivers As DbSet(Of Driver)
    Public Property Addresses As DbSet(Of Address)
    Public Property Contacts As DbSet(Of ContactDetail)
    Public Property Bookings As DbSet(Of Booking)
    Public Property Accounts As DbSet(Of Account)
    Public Property Vehicles As DbSet(Of Vehicle)
End Class
```

There will be more linking of the data later, but my initial problem is as follows. I can create an account which has the following properties..

```
Public Class Account
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Shortcut As String = ""
    Public Property PaymentMethod As PaymentType
    Public Property CardNumber As Integer
    Public Property CardExpiry As New Date(2000, 1, 1)
    Public Property CardSecurity As Integer
    Public Property AccountAddress As Address
    Public Property Contact As ContactDetail
    Public Property Active As Boolean = True
End Class

Public Class ContactDetail
    Public Property Id As Integer
    Public Property Telephone1 As String = ""
    Public Property Telephone2 As String = ""
    Public Property Email1 As String = ""
    Public Property Email2 As String = ""
    Public Property Fax As String = ""

End Class

Public Class Address
    Public Property AddressId As Integer
    Public Property Company As String = ""
    Public Property FlatBuilding As String = ""
    Public Property Road As String = ""
    Public Property Town As String = ""
    Public Property County As String = ""
    Public Property Country As String = ""
    Public Property PostCode As String = ""
End Class
```

I create each account using data from `TextBoxes`, `ComboBoxes` etc. When it comes to saving the data, everything is saved in the appropriate table. The `Accounts` table stores an Id for the appropriate rows in the `Addresses` and `Contacts` tables and the `Address` and `Contact` data from the `Account` are stored there correctly.

**The Problem**

When it comes to retrieving the data for a specific `Account`, neither the `Contact` or `Address` data are returned. All I get are properties with default values. I've tried to follow tutorials on the MS website, but I ALWAYS get an error depending on which way I try to create the navigation. I'm afraid that I don't fully understand what's required. The tutorials are all in C# but I'm certain I get the jist.

**Ultimately I want the address and contact data to be a kind of common pool** that can be linked to from the other tables. But that may become another question once I find out where I'm going wrong right now. These are the methods I use to save and retrieve the data.

`selectedAccount` is an instance of the `Account` class

```
Private Sub AccountSave()
        Using db As New CompanyContext
            If newAccount = True Then
                selectedAccount = New Account
            End If
            With selectedAccount
                .AccountAddress.Company = TxtAccountCompany.Text
                .Shortcut = TxtAccountShortcut.Text
                Select Case CboAccountPaymentMethod.SelectedItem.ToString
                    Case "Account"
                        .PaymentMethod = PaymentType.Account
                    Case "Cash"
                        .PaymentMethod = PaymentType.CashTopay
                    Case "Card"
                        .PaymentMethod = PaymentType.CCToPay
                End Select
                .CardNumber = Integer.Parse(TxtAccountCardNumber.Text)
                .CardExpiry = Date.Parse(MtbAccountCardExpiry.Text)
                .CardSecurity = Integer.Parse(TxtAccountCardSecurity.Text)
                .AccountAddress.FlatBuilding = TxtAccountFlatBuilding.Text
                .AccountAddress.Road = TxtAccountRoad.Text
                .AccountAddress.Town = TxtAccountTown.Text
                .AccountAddress.County = TxtAccountCounty.Text
                .AccountAddress.PostCode = TxtAccountPostcode.Text
                .AccountAddress.Country = TxtAddressCountry.Text
                .Contact.Telephone1 = TxtAccountTelephone1.Text
                .Contact.Telephone2 = TxtAccountTelephone2.Text
                .Contact.Email1 = TxtAccountEmail1.Text
                .Contact.Email2 = TxtAccountEmail2.Text
            End With
            If selectedAccount.Id = 0 Then
                db.Accounts.Add(selectedAccount)
            End If
            db.SaveChanges()
        End Using
        AccountClearInfo()
        AccountDisableEditing()
        AccountRefreshList()
    End Sub
```

```
   Private Sub AccountDisplayInfo()
        If selectedAccount IsNot Nothing Then
            TxtAccountCompany.Text = selectedAccount.AccountAddress.Company
            TxtAccountShortcut.Text = selectedAccount.Shortcut
            TxtAccountOustandingBalance.Text = selectedAccount.OustandingBalance.ToString
            Select Case selectedAccount.PaymentMethod
                Case PaymentType.Account
                    CboAccountPaymentMethod.SelectedText = "Account"
                Case PaymentType.CCToPay
                    CboAccountPaymentMethod.SelectedText = "Card"
                Case PaymentType.CashTopay
                    CboAccountPaymentMethod.SelectedText = "Cash"
            End Select
            TxtAccountCardNumber.Text = selectedAccount.CardNumber.ToString
            MtbAccountCardExpiry.Text = selectedAccount.CardExpiry.ToShortDateString
            TxtAccountCardSecurity.Text = selectedAccount.CardSecurity.ToString
            TxtAccountFlatBuilding.Text = selectedAccount.AccountAddress.FlatBuilding.ToString
            TxtAccountRoad.Text = selectedAccount.AccountAddress.Road.ToString
            TxtAccountTown.Text = selectedAccount.AccountAddress.Town.ToString
            TxtAccountCounty.Text = selectedAccount.AccountAddress.County.ToString
            TxtAccountPostcode.Text = selectedAccount.AccountAddress.PostCode.ToString
            TxtAccountCountry.Text = selectedAccount.AccountAddress.Country.ToString
            TxtAccountTelephone1.Text = selectedAccount.Contact.Telephone1
            TxtAccountTelephone2.Text = selectedAccount.Contact.Telephone2
            TxtAccountEmail1.Text = selectedAccount.Contact.Email1
            TxtAccountEmail2.Text = selectedAccount.Contact.Email2
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

If it's helpful here is the code that was generated behind the scenes for creating each table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Accounts] (
    [Id]                       INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Shortcut]                 NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PaymentMethod]            INT            NOT NULL,
    [CardNumber]               INT            NOT NULL,
    [CardExpiry]               DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    [CardSecurity]             INT            NOT NULL,
    [Active]                   BIT            NOT NULL,
    [AccountAddress_AddressId] INT            NULL,
    [Contact_Id]               INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Accounts] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Accounts_dbo.Addresses_AccountAddress_AddressId] FOREIGN KEY ([AccountAddress_AddressId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Addresses] ([AddressId]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Accounts_dbo.ContactDetails_Contact_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Contact_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[ContactDetails] ([Id])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AccountAddress_AddressId]
    ON [dbo].[Accounts]([AccountAddress_AddressId] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Contact_Id]
    ON [dbo].[Accounts]([Contact_Id] ASC);
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Addresses] (
    [AddressId]    INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Company]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [FlatBuilding] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Road]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Town]         NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [County]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Country]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [PostCode]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Booking_Id]   INT            NULL,
    [Booking_Id1]  INT            NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Addresses] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([AddressId] ASC),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Addresses_dbo.Bookings_Booking_Id] FOREIGN KEY ([Booking_Id]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Bookings] ([Id]),
    CONSTRAINT [FK_dbo.Addresses_dbo.Bookings_Booking_Id1] FOREIGN KEY ([Booking_Id1]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Bookings] ([Id])
);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Booking_Id]
    ON [dbo].[Addresses]([Booking_Id] ASC);


GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_Booking_Id1]
    ON [dbo].[Addresses]([Booking_Id1] ASC);
```

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ContactDetails] (
    [Id]         INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Telephone1] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Telephone2] NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Email1]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Email2]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Fax]        NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.ContactDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Hopefully someone can show me the error of my ways.

Comment: Looking at the Create Table SQL I think the problem is, in your child tables, you're not specifing any link back to Accounts table.  How do you know what Contact Details and Addresses correspond to what Account.  I think you need to include an Account Id column in your child entities

Comment: @hursey Just add something lie `Public Property AccountId As Integer in `Contacts` and `Addresses`? Is it that simple? *Bangs head on wall*

Comment: @Hursey Do I need to add <ForeignKey("not sure what to put here") somewhere? Or something else? By the way thanks for your first response :-) Bed time for me.

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24000907/create-foreign-key-using-data-annotations.  It's C# put has the notations you're after