# Required Field not being validated by ModelState

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I have a `[Products]` class, a `[Product_Types]` class and a `[Products_Product_Types]` class.  I have a Razor page for `[Products_Product_Types]` and ModelState is only validating one of the two `[Required]` ID properties...specifically it's validating the `ProductProductType.ProductId` property and ignoring the `ProductProductType.ProductTypeId` property.  In the code samples below, when I leave the `ProductProductType.ProductTypeId` blank I get this error...

> The value of 'ProductProductType.ProductTypeId' is unknown when
> attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part
> of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is
> not known.

...when instead I expect to see the UnobtrusiveValidation that the `ProductProductType.ProductTypeId` dropdown is required.

I fully expect the issue is in my `DatabaseContext.cs` file, but I've reviewed all the documentation I can find and I'm not sure how to resolve this error.

**Product.cs**

```
public partial class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Name")]
    public string? ProductName { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductType.cs**

```
public partial class ProductType
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Product Type")]
    public string? ProductTypeName { get; set; }
}
```

**ProductsProductType.cs**

```
public partial class ProductsProductType
{
    [Required]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Product Type")]
    public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }

    public virtual Product? Product { get; set; } = null!;
    //public virtual ICollection<Product>? Products { get; set; } = new List<Product>();

    public virtual ProductType? ProductType { get; set; } = null!;
    //public virtual ICollection<ProductType>? ProductTypes { get; set; } = new List<ProductType>();
}
```

**DatabaseContext.cs**

```
public virtual DbSet<ProductsProductType> ProductsProductTypes{ get; set; }

modelBuilder.Entity<ProductsProductType>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => new { e.ProductId, e.ProductTypeId }).HasName("PK_Products_Product_Types");

    entity.ToTable("Products_Product_Types");

    entity.Property(e => e.ProductId).HasColumnName("ProductID");
    entity.Property(e => e.ProductTypeID).HasColumnName("ProductTypeID");

    entity.HasOne(f => f.Product).WithMany(e => e.ProductsProductTypes)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.ProductId).IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Products_Product_Types_Products");

    entity.HasOne(f => f.ProductType).WithMany(e => e.ProductsProductTypes)
        .HasForeignKey(f => f.ProductTypeID).IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
        .HasConstraintName("FK_Product_Product_Types_Product_Types");
});
```

**/ProductsProductTypes/Create.cshtml**

```
<form method="post" asp-page-handler="ProductProductTypeCreate" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-method="post" data-ajax-success="refreshPartial('GetProductProductTypes', 'ProductProductTypes-container')" data-ajax-failure="ajaxValidationHandler">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductProductType.ProductId" value="@ViewBag.ProductId" />
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="ProductProductType.ProductTypeId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="ProductProductType.ProductTypeId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.ProductTypes"><option disabled selected>- Select Product Type -</option></select>
                <span asp-validation-for="ProductProductType.ProductTypeId" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />
                <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="javascript:parent.actionPaneClose();">Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </form>
```

**/ProductsProductTypes/Create.cshtml.cs**

```
[BindProperty]
public ProductsProductType ProductsProductType { get; set; } = default!;

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostProductProductTypeCreateAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid || _context.ProductsProductTypes == null || ProductsProductType == null)
    {
        ViewData["ProductId"] = ProductsProductType.ProductId;
        ViewData["ProductTypes"] = new SelectList(_context.ProductTypes, nameof(ProductType.ProductTypeId), nameof(ProductType.ProductTypeName));
        return Page();
    }

    _context.ProductsProductTypes.Add(ProductsProductType);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return Page();
}
```

Comment: Have you had a chance to look into this [Exception The value of 'X' is unknown when attempting to save changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68507917/exception-the-value-of-x-is-unknown-when-attempting-to-save-changes)?

Comment: '"ModelState is only validating one of the two [Required] ID properties...' What do  you mean ? What's your result of the ModelState.IsValid ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-6.0#non-nullable-reference-types-and-the-required-attribute) related with Non-nullable reference types and the [Required] attribute

> On the server, a required value is considered missing if the property
> is null. A non-nullable field is always valid, and the [Required]
> attribute's error message is never displayed.
>
> However, model binding for a non-nullable property may fail, resulting
> in an error message such as The value '' is invalid.

When you submit the form if you don't set any value in input field,you would see a key-value pair  `key-""`,but if you don't select any option of the dropdown,you won't see the key-value pair

I tried to remove value attribute in your hidden input,disable client validation and submit the form:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="ProductsProductType.ProductId"  />
```

[image]

and get the modelstate err due to failed model binding(if you want to avoid it you may create a viewmodel with int? xxId):

[image]

The error

> The value of 'ProductProductType.ProductTypeId' is unknown when
> attempting to save changes. This is because the property is also part
> of a foreign key for which the principal entity in the relationship is
> not known.

ask you to send the ProductTypeId matches ProductType entity's PK in db

Since you've read all your options from db

```
ViewData["ProductTypes"] = new SelectList(_context.ProductTypes, nameof(ProductType.ProductTypeId), nameof(ProductType.ProductTypeName));
```

make sure you've selected one of the options and enabled client validation

like:

```
@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

in `_ValidationScriptsPartial`:

```
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/lib/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
```

if you still can't enable the client validation,please show us a minimal example of your current  page and  layout view

Comment: many many thanks once again!  You have been most helpful! I would have never figured that out.  It seems counter intuitive to allow a null for a required field is what enables validation.  I changed `public int ProductTypeId { get; set; }` to this `public int? ProductTypeId { get; set; } = null!;` and that one change resolved this issue.  Thank you @ruikaifeng